# Firebase is allowing anything with an @ symbol register in my app

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm building an app for an online course, but I like to take their skeleton and make it better to add to my portfolio, adding features. They're teaching Firebase in this section and building a chat app... When I see their video they use "1@2.com" as their email, which doesn't seem like a real email, so I tried it in mine, and  I noticed that Firebase is allowing me to use a random assortment of whatever, so an obviously not real email "ajflkdsajffadjslfj123412djflakjdf@hotmail.com" to register. I've skimmed through the firebase docs and didn't see anything that says how to check if the email is actually an email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically that could be a valid mail, so there is nothing Firebase can do to check every mails if they are valid or not. What you could do though is to send an email verification to the user and if they verify their account then they can use your application.

Email Verification in Firebase Auth documentation for that can be found [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/02/email-verification-in-firebase-auth.html).